# convert GML to OWL

Tags: xml, converters, owl, gml

I have both .gml and .xsd files for a region and I want to convert it to OWL.
Can anybody suggest me which is the best way to do it?

I found that in some quiet old paper an XSLT style sheet was used. Is it still a good way to do it?